# Html5/Javascript frameworks/server side JS Framework vs Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is if a developer only knows either Html5/Javascript frameworks/server side JS Framework or Ruby on Rails, which skill set will allow him to develop the best web apps or provide greater creativity on the web?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For developing a basic web application you should know about

```
1) Html
2) and one server side technology ( Ruby on Rail/ PHP/ java / Paython etc.. )
```

When it comes to decorate your web application you need

```
1) Css
2) Javascript framework
```

In your case first skill set will provide you more freedom to fly in the world of web.

Comment: He is probably talking about serverside js, for example nodejs.

Comment: yes, server side JS framework == node.js, persevere etc....
The core variable being server side JS, is what made me ponder this question.